# Managing different decimals in a vector - R

Tags: r, decimal

I need to have a list where the first number have a decimal, but the others don't.

Here is an example :

```
to_add = 1.5
main = c(3,5,7 , 9, 11, 13 ,15, 17, 19)

tot = c(to_add,main)

tot
#The problem :
# [1]  1.5  3.0  5.0  7.0  9.0 11.0 13.0 15.0 17.0 19.0
```

Don't really know why but R display a ".0" even though, if we take a look individually, it doesn't :

```
tot[2]
# [1]  3
```

What I do after that is putting this list in the axis of a graph :

```
axis(1, at=tot)
```

If I gave it a list of character, it will convert with the same display as above.

Comment: You can't mix data types in the same object, are you trying to just round all except for the first number in your vector?

Comment: That's true but isn't there any way to go around that ? Yes that's the goal.

Comment: Can you show us a specific example how you are going to use this vector? How will the first and reset of the values be used?

Answer (score 2):

Have a further read on coercion [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html), but the short answer as to why this is happening is that all elements of a vector must be of the same type:

> All elements of an atomic vector must be the same type, so when you
> attempt to combine different types they will be coerced to the most
> flexible type. Types from least to most flexible are: logical,
> integer, double, and character.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two reasons:

The first is *coercion*, as already mentioned by statnet22 above. When you combine elements of different types in a single vector in R, it is cast to a common data type. You cannot have elements of different types in a vector (but a list would work).

Secondly, even if R doesn’t display a decimal number, it may actually be one:

```
b1 = c(3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L)
b2 = as.integer(c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19))
b3 = c(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19) # == main
```

All three vectors `b1`, `b2`, and `b3` are displayed as:

```
# [1]  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Only `b1` and `b2` are actually integer vectors though:

```
str(b1)
# int [1:9] 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
str(b2)
# int [1:9] 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
str(b3)
# num [1:9] 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Nevertheless, when you add a real number such as 1.5 to the vector, all of them will become “numeric” vectors (see *coercion*).

Answer (score 1):

In order to "solve" your issue as described in the other posts (e.g. if you need the numbers for presentation), you could convert the integers and real numbers into character types before concatenating (= they will be stored as strings from then on).

```r
tot <- c(as.character(to_add), as.character(main))
```

Output:

```r
str(tot)
chr [1:10] "1.5" "3" "5" "7" "9" "11" "13" "15" "17" "19"
```

**Update 27/7:**

To use it for a plot, you'll want to use this as the `label` argument too.

The `at`-argument will automatically convert it to numerics, but you might want to keep one for the ticks and for the labels depending on the use-case.

```r
plot(tot, 1:length(tot))
axis(1, at = tot, label = tot)
```

[image]

Comment: I really need number and can't do that with character ...

Comment: In that case why is it it important? What’s the use case? You could potentially put the two vectors in a list instead of a common vector.

Comment: The use case is that I put this list in the axis of a graph and if I give it a list of character, it will convert the list in numbers and thus, display the wrong format.

Comment: See update on how to do that.